# microk8s not granting me permissions to execute commands

Tags: groups, microk8s

Despite being in the `microk8s` OS group and having r-x access to the local config files, I am unable to execute microK8s commands that require elevated permissions.

```
$ groups
gary adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare docker microk8s

$ ls -la ~/.kube
total 12
drwxr-x---  3 gary microk8s 4096 Oct 10 09:23 .
drwxr-x--- 27 gary gary     4096 Oct 14 16:46 ..
drwxr-x---  4 gary microk8s 4096 Oct 10 09:23 cache

$ microk8s status
Insufficient permissions to access MicroK8s.
You can either try again with sudo or add the user gary to the 'microk8s' group:

    sudo usermod -a -G microk8s gary
    sudo chown -f -R gary ~/.kube

After this, reload the user groups either via a reboot or by running 'newgrp microk8s'.
```

I executed the commands it suggests, and have rebooted many times.  Can anyone advise me why microK8s is not granting me permissions?

using Ubuntu 22.4

Comment: There is no version of Ubuntu called 20.4